# Go testing customization with testing.TB

Tags: testing, go, tdd

I'm trying to customize the testing.T with my own `assert` method to lower the number of lines I'm writing. I tried the following, ended with an error: `"wrong signature for TestCustom, must be: func TestCustom(t *testing.T)"`.

How can I make `TestCustom` use `CustomTester` interface with a new method, `assert`?

*I don't want to use a 3rd-party framework.*

**custom_testing.go**

```
type CustomTester struct {
        testing.TB
}

func (t *CustomTester) assert(exp interface{}, act interface{}) {
        if exp != act {
                t.Errorf("expected: %v. got: %v\n", exp, act)
        }
}

// I want testing package inject testing.T here
// But, by using my own wrapper: CustomTester struct with,
// my own assert method to get rid of using t as an argument,
// in each assert like: assert(t, exp, act)
func TestCustom(t *testing.TB) {
        t.assert(3, len(foo))
}
```

---

**NOTE:** *I also tried this, it works but, I don't want to pass `t` each time when I'm testing:*

**working_not_wanted.go**

```
func assert(t *testing.TB, exp interface{}, act interface{}) {
        if exp != act {
                t.Errorf("expected: %v. got: %v\n", exp, act)
        }
}

func TestCustom(t *testing.T) {
        assert(t, 3, len(foo))
}
```

Comment: `t` is how you interact with the testing package, you need to pass it around _somehow_. Have you looked how packages like [`testify`](https://github.com/stretchr/testify) work at all?

Comment: Yeah, I want to interact with `t`, but over my wrapped `CustomTester` interface to ease the burden. Going to look at it now.

Comment: @JimB I want to work with `t` through a receiver as I implemented. I reviewed the `testify`, however [it interacts with `t`](https://github.com/stretchr/testify/blob/master/assert/assertions.go)  in a wrapped variable like: `assert.New(t)` when `t` usage as the first parameter not wanted. I also have tried this and it works of course.

Comment: You can do something like their [`Assertions`](https://godoc.org/github.com/stretchr/testify/assert#Assertions), or a [`Suite`](https://godoc.org/github.com/stretchr/testify/suite#Suite). I'm really not sure what you're asking though -- the `testing` package is going to call the functions with the correct name and signature, and you're free to create structs, subtests, an call methods from within those functions however you choose. You can't somehow make the test package use a different function signature as an entry point.

Comment: If you're going to use your custom wrapper, you may not pass `t` explicitly (because your custom wrapper will), but then you will need to refer to your custom wrapper, so you gain "nothing". However, it is still possible using [method values](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Method_values): the receiver will be implicit and hidden in the method value. I've written a library for this, check out [**github.com/icza/mighty**](https://github.com/icza/mighty).

Comment: @JimB What I'm asking is: **1st:** By using an interface of `testing.T` which is `testing.TB` to add a receiver method for my custom tester which is: `assert` in the question. **2nd:** To be able to switch to my implementation with a receiver method.

Comment: @icza mighty is still using its own wrapper at the beginning of each test function and expects `testing.T`. I already solved it this way. My aim is different. _I'm starting to see that it's not possible in Go right now._

Comment: @inanc Yes, `mighty` also uses a wrapper, but the stress is on **method values**.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Go testing framework executes test functions of a specific signature, and that signature takes a `*testing.T`. If you want to use the stdlib testing system, your test functions have to have the required signature.

You could wrap it with one line in every test function:

```
func MyTest(stdt *testing.T) {
    // This line:
    t := &CustomTester{stdt}
    t.assert(true)
    t.Error("An error done happened")
}
```

There are other ways to do it, but there is no way to have a testing function, run by `go test`, using the stdlib `testing` package, that takes anything other than `*testing.T` as its sole parameter.

Comment: Can't we create something like a catcher automatically for the `testing` package and then redirect it to my custom signature tester?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "catcher", but it sounds like you're describing something that could be considered its own test framework, which you explicitly said you didn't want to do.

Comment: Yeah, I'm looking for a trick to do that. Is it hard to do without an external framework? A few functions to write to do that maybe (_? no clue yet_), not with an external framework. Catcher will act like a proxy.

Comment: No matter what you do, if you want to use Go's test framework, the entrypoint *has to be* a `func(t *testing.T)`. From there, you can do absolutely anything you want; you could use it like a `main()` function to start some entire other handler going. However, the more you diverge, the more you'll have trouble using other tooling that's intended for use with stdlib testing.

Comment: Yeah, I understand that, and I don't want to diverge from `stdlib` either, that's why I was planning to create small helpers for `testing` package. Maybe, some hacky proxy acts before the testing framework. Or a generated code maybe, hmm, that'd be too much I guess.